# Redirect script stdin to file in the background

Tags: shell, background-process, file-descriptors, stdin, fifo

In order to pass my script's stdin to stdin of a command in an alacritty instance it spawns, I'm trying to redirect it to a file in the background (so that the command can start reading it):

```
t="$(mktemp --directory)"
in="$t/in"
#mkfifo "$in"
out="$t/out"
#mkfifo "$out"

cat - 3>"$in" >&3 &
alacritty -e /bin/sh -c "cat '$in' | {...} > '$out'" >&2

cat "$out"
```

As you can see, I tried making it a named pipe, and also using fd3 thinking the problem might be some sort of special casing that backgrounded processes don't get a 'stdin' file descriptor.

In case it's not clear, the reason for trying is that the input may be large enough that I want to start the `...` process without waiting for EOF.

I'm probably going about this all wrong - is there a way to 'reassign' 'my' file descriptors to the shell launched by alacritty? That was my first thought, but I couldn't find anything on passing file descriptors from a shell, just C (etc.) pointers.

Comment: It is not really clear what is not working as expected. Where does the input of the outer script come from? For completeness: what shell is your script running in?

Comment: @fra-san I will use it as `something | this-script | something-else`, where `something` varies, essentially it's to be a poor man's `dmenu` for some cases. Shell - currently just targeting POSIX `/bin/sh`, but requiring `bash` is fine if it somehow really makes life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat - 3>"$in" >&3 &
```

If you run that from a script, `cat`'s stdin will be redirected from `/dev/null`.

If you run it from an interactive shell, `cat` will be stopped by a `SIGTTIN` signal.

In any case, it won't write anything to the `"$in"` pipe.

If that's part of a script, the "solution" (scarequotes because I'm not really clear what you're trying to do) is to "save" the stdin with an `exec [fd]<&0` redirection, and then redirect the input of the background process from that `[fd]`. Compare:

```
echo yes | sh -c 'cat & sleep 1'
```

which won't write anything to stdout, with

```
echo yes | sh -c 'exec 5<&0; cat <&5 & sleep 1'
```

which will do.

Comment: `exec`'s file descriptor behaviour was what I was missing, thank you! The file was because for some reason I thought the file descriptors seen by `alacritty -e /bin/sh` would be different to my script's, a different PID namespace if that's correct terminology. So, `exec 5<&0; alacritty -e /bin/sh -c '<&5 ...'` works well - and I can get the output from redirecting to a file - but is there a way to also redirect that shell's `&1`, so I can 'capture' it in and output it from the script?

Comment: I don't know how I messed that up earlier, just a regular `4>&1` on that command then works fine. Thanks again!